# How to make changes to the fullcalendar UI

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, primeng

How to remove all-day row from the week view of Full Calendar? [Image for my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRCXd.png)

I want to remove that total row which is marked in the above image.

Comment: see the answer below. You didn't spend long reading the documentation, I think.

Comment: @SumanthImandi You can also mark the answer as accepted, if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it by setting `allDaySlot` to `false` when you initialize the fullcalendar object.

[See the doc](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/allDaySlot/)

You can also check [this CodePen](https://codepen.io/sumi1985/pen/rzdXBq), which I forked from [this one](https://codepen.io/lanc/pen/KEqws).